# Setup 'ANDROID_HOME' to run Ionic app on Android device

Tags: android, node.js, ionic-framework

I am trying to install Ionic in my Linux and trying to check how to run the app. I have successfully installed it and run it on browser.

However, I want to run the app on my Android device.

I have tried to run the command `ionic cordova run android --device` but it gives following error:

> (node:11992) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
>   Detected 'adb' command at /usr/bin but no 'platform-tools' directory found near.
>   Try reinstall Android SDK or update your PATH to include valid path to SDK/platform-tools directory.
>       at /home/seven-bits-pc11/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js:287:27
>       at _fulfilled (/home/seven-bits-pc11/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/seven-bits-pc11/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/seven-bits-pc11/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
>       at /home/seven-bits-pc11/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:877:14
>       at runSingle (/home/seven-bits-pc11/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
>       at flush (/home/seven-bits-pc11/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:150:11)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:705:11)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:193:16)
>   (node:11992) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:11992) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I have also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36201240/8730233), but same error is displayed.

**Edit:**

I have also tried [this other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41137754/3342570).

Comment: on which file did you set the two `export` commands?

Comment: You have to path of android sdk to environment variable in linux system

Comment: @Lino I set the two export commands on the ionic project MyApp

Comment: just refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178898/ionic-3-deploy-to-device-set-android-home/48181995#48181995),
This is my answer and hope it helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by correcting the path of ANDROID_HOME as it was mentioned in the links in the question. 
links:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36201240/8730233 and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41137754/3342570.

So, I changed it

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/<installation location>/android-sdk-linux
```

to

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/<installation location>/
```

and my error solved.

Comment: To me not still :(

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your error we can say straight forward there is problem with your Android SDK setup.

Download latest Android SDK from official site.

You can setup ANDROID_HOME path variable to `/sdk-installation-directory/` by adding line in `~/.profile` or `~/bashrc` files on linux system

> export ANDROID_HOME="/sdk-installation-directory"