# Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable in Windows 10 Linux Subsystem

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to run `ionic cordova build --release android`, but that is getting this error.:

```
CordovaError: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
```

I'm using Windows 10, but am using the linux subsystem (so am doing all the linux commands etc...).

I went in to my system variables and put in the Android SDK stuff for Windows as seen here:

[image]

But when I go back into bash/shell, when I do `echo $ANDROID_HOME`, it doesn't show the path I set. Should I instead install Android SDK for linux and have it point to that? Or is there someway I can have this ANDROID_HOME path point to my C:/ drive, as I don't think there is a C:/ drive when I"m on the linux subsystem

Comment: did you restart your cmd after adding environmental variable?

Comment: Yes I restarted both 'bash for ubuntu' on my Windows 10 box, and restarted Webstorm (which has bash built in). yet both times the `echo $ANDROID_HOME` was blank

Comment: havent worked with windows for quite a while.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685699/windows-7-environment-variable-not-working-in-path any of the answers help?

Comment: Probably an issue with converting the windows env var parth (`C:\ `) to a linux path (`\mnt\c`). See [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/12/22/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/) for more info.
I would recommend either switching to the windows cmd or PowerShell or installing Java again on your WSL.

Comment: if you have linux sub system then please refer this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178898/ionic-3-deploy-to-device-set-android-home/48181995#48181995

Comment: can you verify that the windows cmd prompt can pickup your changes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is because the linux sub-system environment variables are separated from Windows environment variables, except for `PATH` which is shared by default starting from Creator Update.

In that case, you have to add `ANDROID_HOME` to the linux environment variable. One way to do it is to add it into `~/.bashrc`

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

add following code to the end of the file

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/mnt/c/Users/<user_name>/AppData/Local/Android/sdk"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools"
```

save, exit and run `source`

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now you will be able to run android sdk tool from linux subsystem, although there is a caveat where you have to add `.exe` for each tool. For example:

```
adb --> won't work
adb.exe --> works
```

Comment: wouldn't it be better to install the Linux version of the sdk on the subsystem ?

Comment: Yes that is much better

Comment: This worked, though for me it was in /mnt/c/Users/<user name>/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk$

Answer (score 2):

So I had written a big answer on this and for some reason I can't find it. I don't know if it didn't get posted or what happened. So re-writing what I written earlier

Windows and Windows Sub System Linux do not by default share any environment variables as such. But there is a way to automatically share variables between the two as explained in below article

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/12/22/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/

By default your `c:\` gets mapped to `/mnt/c`. Now you have two options

**Shell Environments**

You can update your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` (whichever you use) and export the variables

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/mnt/c/Android/sdk"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools"
```

**Shared Environment**

Windows created a special environment variable named `WSLENV`. This environment variable can be used to share the variable between two environments and it will also auto translates paths. Before we dive in some special flags

- **/p**: This flag indicates that a path should be translated between WSL paths and Win32 paths.
- **/l**: This flag indicates the value is a list of paths. In WSL, it is a colon-delimited list. In Win32, it is a semicolon-delimited list.
- **/u**: This flag indicates the value should only be included when invoking WSL from Win32. In the example below, we set FORWSL from cmd and it will show up in WSL.
- **/w**: This flag indicates the value should only be included when invoking Win32 from WSL.

Now if you set the environment like below

```
WSLENV=ANDROID_HOME/p
```

Above says the `ANDROID_HOME` should be shared between WSL and Windows and the `/p` indicates that it should be shared automatically. This is the recommended way of doing it to keep everything in sync

Comment: `export WSLENV=ANDROID_HOME/p` in `.bashrc` did wonders.. had to `ls -s /mnt..` some of the key binaries tho into `/usr/bin/..`